# How do you stop SVN Checkout from bringing back files that were deleted from the project?

Tags: svn, ankhsvn

We are new to the subversion, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn stack.   While in Studio 2008 we have deleted files from our project problem is when we do an svn checkout in our CI build we get the deleted files.   How do I prevent these files from being included in the checkout?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to delete them in Subversion. From the TortoiseSVN menu, chose "Delete", then commit that deletion. On the command line, you can use `svn rm <filename>`, and then commit.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've done an SVN delete (Ankh should offer this option when deleting files through VS, or you can do it manually using Tortoise in Explorer). Once you've committed that change, the file will not be part of the head revision in SVN.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio there's a difference between 'Remove' and 'Delete'. Delete is the default action when you press the 'del' key when in a C# project; in a C++ project the default is 'Remove'.

In case of a remove event, AnkhSVN doesn't svn delete the file, because without AnkhSVN installed, VS wouldn't remove it from disk either.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting files from project only is not enough: SVN doesn't know a thing about "projects", all it knows about are files in your working copy, so you have to delete these "physically" from within the Explorer and then commit changes.