# Why does svn checkout include files that have been deleted from the repository?

Tags: svn

I have a repo on a Linux box and when I browse the repo via TortoiseSVN I can see that certain folders have been deleted from the repo (as they should be), and yet when I do a fresh "svn checkout" (to a new folder) on the Linux box it attempts to retrieve those deleted files.

Why is SVN retrieving these deleted files, and how can I tell it not to do so?

I saw this similar question but it doesn't address my problem:

[How do you stop SVN Checkout from bringing back files that were deleted from the project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709968/how-do-you-stop-svn-checkout-from-bringing-back-files-that-were-deleted-from-the)

Comment: Are you sure you're browsing the repository (and not the working copy), and the right branch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only a few reasons SVN will restore a file that's been deleted.

1. The file was deleted in a branch, and you checkout from a different branch which still contains the file.
2. The file was deleted in the current "HEAD" revision, and you are checking out an older revision where the file used to exist (when you svn update to the deleted revision under this scenario, the file will disappear).
3. The "svn delete ..." command was issued, but you failed to commit the deletion back to the SVN tree with "svn commit ...".

Most of the time it's #3 that causes the confusion, as a SVN delete doesn't imply an automatic commit (so you can couple a delete with other changes).